# Setting up an x-callback url

Tags: ios, http, post, soundcloud

I need to do this for the Soundcloud API and I have no idea what this is about or how to do it. There is a form on the Soundcloud API Developer website where you save your callback URL, but I'm not sure what sort of information I should input there.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe this callback url is for oauth authentication, correct?  i needed to do the same thing for twitter and ended up setting up a custom url scheme for my app (ie appname://oauth) and using this as the callback url.

in case you want to try this, [see this article](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) on how to launch your app via a custom url scheme.  specifically for twitter, you can see [jaanus's post](http://jaanus.com/post/3020644963/plainoauth-now-handles-the-easier-url-callback-flow-in) on some implementation details and the [github project](https://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth).

while i haven't integrated with soundcloud, i did find that they have an objective-c api that you may want to check out if you aren't already [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/).

**update**

so what i mentioned is true - that you can use a custom url scheme and such to handle the authentication, but it's not exactly required.  i found [this article](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Usage.md) which outlines two methods for authentication - the first is for ios4 only and requires very little code.  the second should work on 3.x and uses the custom url method i mentioned above (and outlines how to use it to authenticate).

so to answer your question once and for all, i suggest you:

1. look at this [readme](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/README.md) for the objective-c soundcloud api.
2. read this [setup guide](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Setup.md).
3. then read this [usage guide](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Usage.md).
4. check out this [test iphone application](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/tree/master/TestApps/iPhoneTestApp).

hope this helps!

Comment: Okay this seems like a good start. Indeed, I am using the soundcloud api, but I'm having trouble. I will check out your links and see how I far I can get. But any more info is greatly appreciated... I'm a novice! Thanks again.